# Prevent auto-addition of space before and after XAML Inline among text

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

Ok, so this is a little annoyance of mine with Visual Studio 2010 + XAML in WPF.  I would like to insert Hyperlink elements or Run elements in my XAML.  However, Visual Studio really likes to put said elements on a new line when you create them, and add a space after them.  So, the following code:

```
(<Hyperlink Command="{Binding References}">Click Here for references</Hyperlink>)
```

will turn into:

```
(
<Hyperlink Command="{Binding References}">Click Here for references</Hyperlink> )
```

when I click Ctrl-K Ctrl-D (which I do often) to format the document.  This kind of behavior also happens when I paste the first bit of code somewhere else, or even as I type the hyperlink itself.

Ultimately, the code ends up rendering something like this:

( Click Here for references )

Which just looks silly with too many spaces and requires manual removal.

I have many hyperlinks in my code and probably equally many Run's.

**What can I do to remove this default behavior in Visual Studio?**

P.S. Links are welcome- I have tried to search around and haven't found anything yet.